# VeeValidate - custom validation functions in ES5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arrow-functions, vee-validate

I'm creating a custom validation rule using VeeValidate. The offical docs uses arrow functions for the `getMessage` and `validate` methods. How do I implement these functions in the regular function syntax?

```
VeeValidate.Validator.extend('verify_username', {
  getMessage: field => 'Your username must be 3-24 characters long, \
    contains only a-z, 0-9, a period or an underscore, and should begin \
    with an alphabetic character.',
  validate: value => /^[a-z][a-z0-9._]{2,23}$/.test(value)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use arrow function, you can just pass a normal function in its place as:

```
VeeValidate.Validator.extend('verify_username', {
  getMessage: function (field) {
    return "username must be..."
  },
  validate: function (value) {
    return "[...]"
  }
});
```

---

These functions are identical:

```
(foo) => 'bar';
```

is the same as:

```
function (foo) {
  return 'bar'
}
```

Comment: can you have a look at a vee-validate related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444033/vue-js-bootstrapvue-veevalidate-cannot-validate-datepicker ?