# Vue.js and vue-phone-number-input package component : set country code and phone number programmatically

Tags: validation, vue.js, phone-number, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

In my Laravel + Vue.js SPA (Single Page Application), I am using [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) , 
[vue-phone-number-input](https://github.com/LouisMazel/vue-phone-number-input) package  and [VeeValidate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/). Upon inputting the country code and phone number, I can retrieve them seperately in the `methods` part.

The mobile (or phone) number input is inside a form. After validating the form, I save the data ( country code and phone number each, as **the component has 2 parts: country code and phone number. See the image in the provided link of the package**) in database table. When the form page loads, input fields should also have values fetched from the database.

But I cannot find a way to set the value to the mobile (or phone) input field correctly.

Let me paste the code here :

```
<template>
 <ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ passes }">

        <div id="registration_form">

            <b-form @submit.prevent="passes(onSubmit)" @reset="resetForm">

               <ValidationProvider vid="mobile" rules="required" name="mobile" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">

                    <b-form-group
                            label="Mobile:"
                            label-for="exampleInput1"

                    >

                        <vue-phone-number-input

                                v-model="mobile"
                                default-country-code="BD"
                                required
                                :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
                                @update="updatePhoneNumber"
                                placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"
                        />



                        <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>

                    </b-form-group>

                </ValidationProvider>

                <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
                <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>
            </b-form>

        </div><!-- end of id registration_form-->
    </ValidationObserver>
</template>
```

JS part has the following content. Somehow I manage to get the `user_profile` object variable to  contain the country code (`nationalNumber`) and phone number without country code (`phoneNumber`) from the database table.

```
 import VuePhoneNumberInput from 'vue-phone-number-input';
 import 'vue-phone-number-input/dist/vue-phone-number-input.css';

    export default {
        name: "EditProfile",
        components: {
            ValidationObserver,
            ValidationProvider,
            VuePhoneNumberInput
        },
        data: () => ({

            mobile:user_profile.phoneNumber,
            national_number:user_profile.nationalNumber,



        }),


        methods: {
            updatePhoneNumber(data) {
                this.mobile = data.phoneNumber;
                this.national_number = data.nationalNumber;

            },
            onSubmit() {
                console.log("Form submitted yay!");
},
            resetForm() {
                this.name = "";
                this.email = "";
                this.address="";
                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    this.$refs.form.reset();
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

So how can I set the country code and phone (or mobile) number to the `vue-phone-number-input` component programmatically ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this library has a critical bug:
https://github.com/LouisMazel/vue-phone-number-input/issues/125

In short: currently it's impossible to initialize this component with phone number so that the country code would be selected based on the input.

Answer (score 2):

You set the phone # to start by using `v-model` - it's a two way binding.  For the country code, you use `v-bind` on `default-country-code` like this:

```
<vue-phone-number-input
  v-model="mobile"
  :default-country-code="national_number"
  required
  :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
  @update="updatePhoneNumber"
  placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"
/>
```

Comment: can you have a look at a Vue.js related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458265/vue-js-access-data-property-from-within-template-without-using-props-in-vue-fi >