# How can I access data property from within template without using props in Vue file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

In my Laravel + Vue.js SPA (Single Page Application), I am using [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) and [VeeValidate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#validate-before-submit).

In `EditProfile.vue` file, I want to access the data property namely `default_country_code` from an attribute in the template namely `default_country_code`.

I can achieve it by using `props` i.e:  having a data attribute in Vue root instance and then using it in the template with the help of `props` in `EditProfile.vue` file.

**But I want to use it in the template without using any `props`**. Because if I use `props`,  all the props that I need to use in template sections in different pages have to be defined in Vue root instance . And when those data attributes that will be used as `props` come from database, I have to make multiple queries in DB in the corresponding Laravel controller method and use them in Vue root instance. And this approach does not seem to be any loosely coupled architecture to me.

In `EditProfile.vue` page, I have :

```html
    <template>     
             <ValidationProvider vid="name" rules="required" name="name" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                           
                  <b-form-group
                                    label="Name:"
                                    label-for="exampleInput1"
        
                            >


                      <b-form-input

                                v-model="name"
                                default-country-code="default_country_code"
                                :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)" 
                                placeholder="Enter Name"

                       ></b-form-input
        
                                <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
    
                  </b-form-group>

             </ValidationProvider>
        
</template>         
                        
        
        export default {
                name: "EditProfile",
                props: {
        
                },
               data: () => ({
                    name:"Mr. XYZ",
                    default_country_code:"FR"
        
                })
        
        };
```

How can I use `default_country_code` in template attribute without using any `props` by taking help of the Vue root instance as I said before ?

Comment: You can use a centralized store like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to store data that should be used across components.

Comment: @RossAllen,  any way without using `Vuex` ?

Comment: If you write something to support your use case you'll be writing a small, limited version of Vuex. I recommend adding Vuex because it'll come in useful as you add more functionality too.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're trying to access the value from a child component, you can access Vue's state. For example `let someVar = $parent.default_country_code`.

That said, using `props` or something like `vuex` to store global state, would be better practice.

Comment: why do you need to access parent ?

Comment: I'm assuming that's where the data is. If you're passing data via props to a child component (then the data exists in the component that calls the child componente). Thus inside the child component you ask for the parent's data.

Comment: I said I would not use `props`.

Comment: You asked why $parent. And I explained that in *your example* using props the data exsits in the parent component. Therefor without props you would access the data from WITHIN the CHILD by using $parent.